# How to make a geography field unique?

Tags: django, gis, postgis, geodjango, django-postgresql

I have this model:

```
class Marker(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(geography=True, unique=True)
```

When I try to add a Marker instance through the admin interface, it raises a `ValueError`:

```
File "django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111. response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  366. return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  196. return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25. return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21. return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  209. return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  937. if form.is_valid():
File "django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  124. return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  115. self.full_clean()
File "django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  272. self._post_clean()
File "django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  338. self.validate_unique()
File "django/forms/models.py" in validate_unique
  347. self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
File "django/db/models/base.py" in validate_unique
  633. errors = self._perform_unique_checks(unique_checks)
File "django/db/models/base.py" in _perform_unique_checks
  724. if qs.exists():
File "django/db/models/query.py" in exists
  565. return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
File "django/db/models/sql/query.py" in has_results
  441. return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
File "django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  808. sql, params = self.as_sql()
File "django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  82. where, w_params = self.query.where.as_sql(qn=qn, connection=self.connection)
File "django/db/models/sql/where.py" in as_sql
  91. sql, params = child.as_sql(qn=qn, connection=connection)
File "django/db/models/sql/where.py" in as_sql
  94. sql, params = self.make_atom(child, qn, connection)
File "django/contrib/gis/db/models/sql/where.py" in make_atom
  47. spatial_sql = connection.ops.spatial_lookup_sql(data, lookup_type, params_or_value, lvalue.field, qn)
File "django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py" in spatial_lookup_sql
  497. '"%s" lookup.' % lookup_type)

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/coremap/marker/add/
Exception Value: PostGIS geography does not support the "exact" lookup.
```

According to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geography-type), a `geography` type really doesn't have the `exact` field lookup. There is any way to accomplish the `unique` constraint without use `exact`?

I'm using:

- Postgresql 9.1
- PostGIS 1.5
- Django 1.4.3

Comment: congratulations :) looks like a bug to me - you should test a reinstall within a VM to double-check that it's not the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I got into similar problem but with a newer version of Django (1.10.5), PostGIS (2.0) and Postgres (9.4) (Op's question its 4 years from this answer)

The error that Django raised to me was a bit different, but is related:

`ValueError: PostGIS geography does not support the "~=" function/operator.`

Turns out that the Django PostGIS backend, in this version, uses the "~=" operator to verify if a certain record already exists, but this is not supported by PostGIS on geography types. Not sure why GeoDjango devs didn't used the "=" operator which is supported by both geography and geometry types.

So the solution I found was to monkey-patch the Django PostGIS backend by adding in the top of the models.py file (maybe there is more elegant ways to do this monkey-patching), but worked fine to me...

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis.operations import (PostGISOperator,
                                                               PostGISOperations,
                                                               BILATERAL)
PostGISOperations.gis_operators['exact'] = PostGISOperator(op='=', 
                                                           geography=True, 
                                                           raster=BILATERAL)
PostGISOperations.gis_operators['same_as'] = PostGISOperator(op='=', 
                                                             geography=True, 
                                                             raster=BILATERAL)
```

I suppose that if you still are using older versions of Django and PostGIS on your project you may want to verify if the given operators are supported and how the backend operators are handled in that particular version of Django.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can do this directly in Django or whether you will need to add the index after the fact, but PostgreSQL does support unique functional indexes.

You can enforce a unique geometry using something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_geometry_idx_u ON mytable(geometry_to_text(mygeom));
```

This will create a unique index on the textual representation of the geometry column.  There may be limitations on size (I don't expect that indexes will work well for toasted values) but if you have that many points in your geometry fields then you are going to have issues otherwise with unique constraints.